# Event fired when lightning:inputField is required

Tags: lightning-aura-components

```
<lightning:inputField fieldName="MyMasterDetail__c"/>
```

So that field is obviously required, and there's an `onblur` event that checks its value and notifies the user when blank (red border and some text underneath the field).
Is there a way for me to capture that event as well? It's screwing up my layout...

Nice, normal layout.
[image: Nice, normal layout]
All wonky because of the `required` notification.

[image: All screwed up because of "required".]

```
<lightning:layout horizontalAlign="spread" verticalAlign="end">
    <lightning:layoutItem size="9">
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="MyMasterDetail__c" value="{!v.selectedRecord}"/>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:button variant="neutral" type="button" label="Search records" onclick="{!c.showAllrecords}"/>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
```

I'd like to add some conditional formatting to the `<lightning:layout>` so that if the `required` message shows up, it should `verticalAlign="center"` instead of `end`.

Answer (score 0):

Specifically for this case I have a workaround, but I can see how being able to capture that event is useful, so I'll just leave my workaround here and hope someone has a solution.

My workaround is to pad the top of my button with a blank line that takes up the same vertical space as the input's Label, and `verticalAlign="start"`. It's a mess.

```
<lightning:layout horizontalAlign="spread" verticalAlign="start">
    <lightning:layoutItem size="9">
        <lightning:inputField fieldName="MyMasterDetail__c" value="{!v.selectedRecord}"/>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
    <lightning:layoutItem>
        <lightning:layout multipleRows="true">
            <lightning:layoutItem size="12">
                <div class="slds-form-element__label">&nbsp;</div>
            </lightning:layoutItem>
            <lightning:button variant="neutral" type="button" label="Search records" onclick="{!c.showAllrecords}"/>
        </lightning:layout>
    </lightning:layoutItem>
</lightning:layout>
```